# Plotly: How can I change the format of hover-on labels?

Tags: plotly

I've looked through online documentation, but couldn't find how to change the format of hover-on labels:

[image: screenshot]

For example, if I'd like to display the number as "~611 thousand" or something of the sort.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plotly tick and hover formatting are fully customizable using the [python / d3 formatting language](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#numbers).

From an API, use axis attributes `'tickformat'` and `'hoverformat'` to set the behavior. For example, [this graph](https://plot.ly/~etpinard/3822/the-us-state-and-federal-prison-population-has-increased-800-in-just-40-years/) has `'layout.yaxis.hoverformat': ',f'`.

From the web app, input your formatting specs under "Axes" -> "Labels":

[image]

Comment: I can't find "hovermode" in the code of the example you provide. Nor could I make it work for my plot. Could you please clarify?

Comment: If you click on the "Code" tab, you can view the code in any language you want. Try JSON for instance. You will see `hovermode: "x"` as a top-level attribute under `layout`, and `hoverformat': ',f'` under `yaxis`, which is under `layout`.

Comment: @etpinard , @abalter , @Mikhail : I went through the specifiers in documentation but can't figure out how to specify the format string so that e.g. number `611150` would display as `~611 thousand`. Could you be please more specific and help to provide the `hoverformat` value for such a case?

Answer (score 1):

Plotly allows for axis and hover format only String values, so you cant write your own function to format labels with such unusual style.

So I see only one solution -- change created hover tooltip using jquery and "on_hover" event:

```
result.on('plotly_hover', function (eventdata){
  /*
   * var hoverTooltip = $(".hovertext", result)[0],
   *     hoverText = $("text", hoverTooltip).get(0),
   *     hoverFrame = $("path", hoverTooltip).get(0);
   *
   *  do what you want here
   *
   */
})
```

But it's a lot of work here (you must take into account size and position of the hover tooltip also)