# Plotly.js shows not full name of trace when hovering over

Tags: angular, typescript, plotly

I made a graph with plotly in angular app, but the trace has a long name.
So when I hover over my graph, the name is shortened by putting ... behind it. I really don't want this. How can I change this?

This is my code.

```
 var text = "Plot_ForecastConfig";
    var layout = {
      showlegend: true,
      legend: {"orientation": "h"},
      yaxis: {
        title: 'Sales',
        titlefont: {
          family: 'Courier New, monospace',
          size: 18,
          color: '#7f7f7f'
        }
      }
    };
    var options = {
      scrollZoom: true,
      showLink: false,
      modeBarButtonsToAdd: [{
        name: 'image',
        title: 'Download plot as a png',
        icon: Plotly.Icons.camera,
        click: function () {
          Plotly.downloadImage(document.getElementById('graph'), {
            filename: text,
            format: 'png',
            height: 700,
            width: 1000
          });
        }
      }],
      modeBarButtonsToRemove: ['toImage', 'zoom2d', 'pan', 'pan2d', 'sendDataToCloud', 'hoverClosestCartesian', 'autoScale2d'],
      displaylogo: false,
      displayModeBar: true,
    };

    Plotly.newPlot('graph', this.drawing, layout, options);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could get the long name to be displayed by just adding below line in my trace object.

```
hoverlabel: {namelength :-1}
```

Here is a working example.

```js
Plotly.plot('graph', [{
  y: [2,1,2],
  name: 'loooooooooooooooooooooooooong text name',
  hoverinfo: "y+name",
  hoverlabel: {namelength :-1},
}])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Plotly has a new attribute [`namelength`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#scatter-hoverlabel-namelength) which can be used for that purpose, see the other answer by Rajshekar Reddy.

> namelength (integer or array of integers greater than or equal to -1)
>
> Sets the length (in number of characters) of the trace name in the
>   hover labels for this trace.
>
> -1 shows the whole name regardless of length.
>
> 0-3 shows the first 0-3 characters, and
>
> an integer >3 will show the whole name if it is less than that many characters, but if it  is longer, will truncate to `namelength - 3` characters and add an
>   ellipsis.

If you want to do it manually the solution below still works.

You could either assign the trace `name` to `text` as well and set `hoverinfo` to `x+y+text` or modify the `hovertext` object yourself (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948996/2776376) for a more detailed explanation).

```js
var _this = {
  drawing: [{
    x: [1, 2, 3],
    y: [1, 2, 5],
    text: "Yeah, that's a really long name, let's see what Plotly does to it",
    name: "Yeah, that's a really long name, let's see what Plotly does to it",
    hoverinfo: "x+y+name"
  }]
};

var myPlot = document.getElementById('graph1');
Plotly.newPlot(myPlot, _this.drawing);
_this.drawing[0].hoverinfo = 'x+y+text';
Plotly.newPlot('graph2', _this.drawing);


myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(data) {
  var infotext = data.points.map(function(d) {

    if (d.x > 1) {
      return d.data.name;
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  });

  if (infotext[0] === "") {
    return;
  }
  var hoverinfo = Plotly.d3.selectAll('.hovertext').selectAll('.name');
  var cloned = Plotly.d3.selectAll('.hovertext').append(hoverinfo.property("nodeName"));
  var attr = hoverinfo.node().attributes;
  for (var j = 0; j < attr.length; j += 1) {
    cloned.attr(attr[j].name, attr[j].value);
  }
  cloned[0][0].innerHTML = infotext[0];
  hoverinfo.attr('opacity', 0);
  cloned.attr('opacity', 1);
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
<div id='graph1'></div>
<div id='graph2'></div>
```